# audio_service not showing title in the notification

Tags: android, flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

help me guys implement audio_service in my flutter app , i have already working audio service  the cotrols the audio i just want to pair it with audio_service .
at the begining i'm trying to make things hard code just to see how it works then pair it with my audio service.

here is  the code

```
class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler
    with QueueHandler, // mix in default queue callback implementations
        SeekHandler { // mix in default seek callback implementations

  // The most common callbacks:

  void addd(){
    queue.add([const MediaItem(id: "dd", title: "ss",duration: Duration(seconds: 40))]);
    playbackState.add(
      PlaybackState(
        queueIndex: 0,
        playing: true,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.loading
      )
    );
  }
  @override
  Future<void> play()async {
    playbackState.add(
     playbackState.value.copyWith(
       processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready,
      playing: true,
      controls: [MediaControl.play],
    )
    );
    dev.log("playing");
  }
  @override
  Future<void> pause() async {
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
      playing: false,
      controls: [MediaControl.pause],
    ));
    dev.log("pause is called");
  }
  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    dev.log("stop is caleld");
  }
  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) async {
     dev.log("seek is called");
  }
  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int i) async {
       dev.log("seek is called");
  }
}
```

i tried to hard code a audio in the function addd , in another place i first call addd then play , which seems to be partialy working , since the control buttons are working as expected  :

- when i click pause or play the correct icon is shown
  but the problem is no title is shown and also i can't see no progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to broadcast the current media item:

```dart
item = MediaItem(id: "dd", title: "ss", duration: Duration(seconds: 40));
mediaItem.add(item);
```

Comment: one question please is it normal that i can't seek from the notification

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a separate question for that, but of course search first to see if that question already exists and has an answer.